# Where can I observe a world's creation as it happens?

Tags: campaign-development, map-making, maps, adventurer-conqueror-king, session-summaries

The Adventurer Conquerer King System has specific and detailed instructions on how to map and detail a setting for use in play, and I'm trying to get the hang of them. Unfortunately, not having a real frame of reference for this style of setting generation is holding back my understanding, and it occurs to me the process would be a lot easier if I had an example to check each stage against.

Is there anyone who has documented each step of their ACKS campaign setting creation online, that I might see what they did? Failing that, has anyone built a campaign setting that strictly adheres to the ACKS campaign setting creation rules that I could use as a reference?

I'm *not* looking for system-agnostic information, instructions or advice on how to design and flesh out a fantasy world, as there's already a number of fine resources of that sort available. Instead, I'm looking for an aid to understanding the setting generation rules of the ACKS, in the form of a detailed description or example of those rules being applied.

Answer (score 2):

This [forum thread](http://www.autarch.co/forums/actual-play/my-acks-campaign-setting-frost-bitten-lands) has an ACKS-style campaign map and regional map, and descriptions of the various realms including population densities, major cities, and trade routes.

It goes some way towards what you are looking for.

Also [this one](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?686639-ACKS-My-Campaign-world-Spirits-Terror-Birds-and-Old-Kings-%28advice-welcome!%29) (a different GM, still using ACKS) has some more piece by piece development and description.

Comment: Karl, please annotate your answer with useful quotes from the threads. Link rot on forums can be deadly, and this answer is useless without the links.

Comment: Thanks for these; They're something like what I'm looking for, though neither goes into great detail on the application of rules.

Answer (score 1):

While not specifically ACKS, I have worked examples for each step of my [How to build a fantasy sandbox](http://batintheattic.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-make-fantasy-sandbox.html) series. The authors of ACKS and I correspond and have exchanged ideas so there are some common issue we both address. In the post there is a link to a PDF Download.

Comment: While this does seem useful for anyone developing a world, it's lack of specificity to ACKS does preclude it being the reliable example of rules-in-action that I'm looking for. Thanks for the valuable resource, though.